# Can I change/reduce the error level for a log in log4net?

Tags: log4net

I'm working with a third-party SDK that uses log4net.  I don't want to completely exclude their items from the log; however, I don't want to constantly see these Error items in our logs either.  Seeing them as Warnings or Infos, however, would be what I really want.

Is there any way to configure log4net to reduce the level of an alert so that it's not showing up as an error (within the .config file)?

Answer (score 1):

Not something I have tried, but perhaps you could define a different conversionPattern for their classes with the level hard-coded.

ie, if your standard pattern is something like

```
  <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger %ndc - %message%newline" />
```

then you could define theirs to be

```
  <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] WARN  %logger %ndc - %message%newline" />
```

or maybe move their errorlevel to be part of the message, ie

```
  <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] WARN  %logger %ndc - %-5level-%message%newline" />
```

The usual method of doing something like this is to configure their log to go to a different place (ie different file or database).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, read the configuration manual here

http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html

and make changes to your config file accordingly and show up logs which you want.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I've read that already.  What settings can you use to actually change the level of the alert?  That link (and all other apache documentation I've seen) doesn't talk about this concept.